# SSIS - Import and Export wizard - Dataflow OLE Destination create not executed before injecting data?

Tags: sql-server-2014, ssis

I've created an SSIS package using the Import and Export Wizard using SSDT to generate the package.

After analyzing this package I see that it consists of a **SQL Execution Task** to create the table and then a Data flow with a **OLE DB Source** and a **OLE DB Destination**

What I found odd was that the **OLE DB Destination** also contains a create statement to create the table. In my logicI assumed that if a table did not yet exist in the destination DB that this statement would create it on the fly.
Sadly tho, without executing the SQL Execution Task (Prep Task) the Data flow fails as it does not see the destination table to inject to.

Would it not make sense that the OLE DB Destination component create the table using the specified CREATE SQL statement (or do I need to check some obscure option for this?) thus making the SQL Prep task obsolete?

From what I can see this is **not** the case so I'm a bit confused about the logic behind having to both do a SQL CREATE statement in a Prep Task and additionally still define it also as (*the same*) CREATE statement in the OLE DB Destination component.
Disable'ing the Prep task results in an error stating the table does not exist yet so from this I deduce that the CREATE prep task is mandatory (or at least the table creation) before attempting an injection

Anybody got some more details about this or can help me make sense of it (it being why we need to both define the CREATE in the Prep task and in the OLE DB Destination)?